# backbone js more than one class and function not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

When I tried with a single class and property it works fine. But if I'm using it with multiple class properties, it throws an error, such that `mixchi` is not a function.

```
var sinchan = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
    himavari: function() {
        return "sinchan nuhara"; 
    }
}, {
    mixchi: function() {
        return "10";
    }
});
console.log(sinchan.himavari());//output sinchan nuhara
console.log(sinchan.mixchi());// output TypeError: sinchan.mixchi is not a function
```

Comment: Question not clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you took that, but [Backbone's `extend`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) function doesn't work like that.

## How to use `extend`

> ```
> Backbone.Model.extend(properties, [classProperties])
> ```
>
> To create a **Model** class of your own, you extend **Backbone.Model** and
>   provide instance **properties**, as well as optional **classProperties** to be
>   attached directly to the constructor function.

Your first example works because you're defining `himavari` in the `classProperties` object (second param of `extend`) which is the equivalent of a static function.

```js
// this defines a custom model class
var MyModelClass = Backbone.Model.extend({
  instanceFunc: function() {
    return this.get('test');
  },
  otherInstanceFunc: function() {
    return this.get('other');
  }
}, {
  // 'this' is not available in the following functions
  staticFunc: function() {
    return "static";
  },
  otherStaticFunc: function() {
    return "other static"
  }
});

// This is how you create an instance of a custom model class
var modelInstance = new MyModelClass({
  test: 'test value',
  other: 'other'
});

console.log(modelInstance.instanceFunc());
console.log(modelInstance.otherInstanceFunc());
// console.log(modelInstance.staticFunc()); 
// => TypeError: modelInstance.staticFunc is not a function
// console.log(modelInstance.otherStaticFunc());
// => TypeError: modelInstance.otherStaticFunc is not a function

// console.log(MyModelClass.instanceFunc());
// => TypeError: MyModelClass.instanceFunc is not a function
// console.log(MyModelClass.otherInstanceFunc());
// => TypeError: MyModelClass.otherInstanceFunc is not a function
console.log(MyModelClass.staticFunc());
console.log(MyModelClass.otherStaticFunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```